# What will happen if I call Start method without run() in thread extended class?

Tags: java, multithreading

My JavaApplication class extends the Thread class, but does not having run method. If I run the below code how does start method works and behaves?

```
public class JavaApplication1 extends Thread {
    // public void run(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication ja = new JavaApplication();
        ja.start();
    }
}
```

Could anyone give some advise on this?

Comment: Did you try executing the code? What happens?

Comment: @BackSlash It is Possible Duplicate ?

Comment: The answer is in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--. *If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.*.

Answer (score 1):

It will run the run() method in Thread which will do nothing and end.

From JDK 8

```
/**
 * If this thread was constructed using a separate
 * <code>Runnable</code> run object, then that
 * <code>Runnable</code> object's <code>run</code> method is called;
 * otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.
 * <p>
 * Subclasses of <code>Thread</code> should override this method.
 *
 * @see     #start()
 * @see     #stop()
 * @see     #Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable, String)
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is the default constructor for Thread.

Answer (score 1):

By default, run() method in the Thread class:

```
/* What will be run. */
private Runnable target;

@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

So, if you will not override **run()** method - nothing will not happen, target will be null

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special. `Thread` class contains default implementation of `run()` method. By default it **do not anything**.